# How to create a loop which has x nested loops the value of which is determined by the user in java?

Tags: java, loops, nested

How do I create a loop which has a unknown number of nested loops, the value of which is determined by the user? For example, lets say we take an input in a variable `x`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = in.nextInt();
```

I just cannot figure out what to do next.

Comment: We need more details. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You can't magically make the code re-write itself at runtime to have "n" nested loops (well, actually you can, but let's not go there), but you can use *recursion* for a similar effect,